# Ruby - class starting a thread is never disposed by GC

Tags: ruby, multithreading, garbage-collection

I'm new to Ruby so I apologize if I'm missing something. I have a class that starts a thread to perform some internal caching refresh. Even if I join the thread and set it to nil, and then set to  nil all the class instances the class is not disposed. Has anyone seen this issue? What am I doing wrong?
Thx
Daniele

My repro:

```
class KK
    def initialize()
      @thread = Thread.new(&method(:refresh_cache))      
      ObjectSpace.define_finalizer( self, self.class.finalize() )
    end

    def self.finalize()
      proc {       
        puts 'Object KK Disposed'
      }
    end

    def wait_thread
      puts 'join thread'
      @thread.join #also tried with exit and kill
      @thread=nil
    end

    def refresh_cache
          puts 'KK still here'    
    end    
end

puts 'started'

puts Thread.list

k2=KK.new
puts    ObjectSpace.each_object(KK).count

puts Thread.list
k2.wait_thread
k2=nil
puts 'After nil'
puts Thread.list

GC.start
sleep 5
#still one instance here
puts    ObjectSpace.each_object(KK).count
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `&foo` desugars to `foo.to_proc`
2. `&method(:bar)` desugars to `method(:bar).to_proc`
3. symbol lookup will have to retrieve `method`, which is an instance method inherited from `Object`, i.e. it's `self.method(:bar).to_proc`.

`self.method` produces a *bound* `Method`, which keeps the bound receiver (self) alive and it keeps doing so when wrapped into a proc.

You should use a static method if you want to turn it into a proc that can be passed to a thread without holding onto the instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear to me that since I have a thread bound to an instance method I have a reference open, my expectation was once I disposed the thread setting it to nil, the reference would go away and the object itself could be disposed. Since the cache I need to implement is per instance (every instance is a device) I cannot use a class method. I am new to Ruby, but immo it badly misses destructors.

Comment: GC runs asynchronously, you should not expect *immediate* disposal.

Comment: that's way I started it, I'm pretty sure the object is never disposed even if I set the thread property to nil. Anyway thank you all, I learned some more of Ruby internals and in the meantime changed my design so that device instances are created just one and maintained throughout the lifetime of the code, so I don't have any leak any more.